# Compressing in express response removes data

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, zlib

I have created a expressjs server that gets elements from a Redis database, transforms them into JSON and pipes them through the response object. The data I am sending is quite big and I think I would greatly benefit from data compression in this case.

The problem is that when i use zlib's `createGzip()` function, on the receiver side I do not receive all of the information (In fact, from the 56800 objects I should be receiving I only receive 3000 to 4000 objects, this number varies every time I request the data). When there is no gzip compression, the 56800 objects arrive perfectly. (I have tried this both using chrome and a JS script with axios to test)

I am pipelining it using

```js
import { createClient, RedisClientType, SchemaFieldTypes } from 'redis'
import stream from 'node:stream'

type SupportedMessageTypes = 'cam' | 'cpm'

interface GeoPosition {
    longitude: number
    latitude: number
}

interface OutputItemType {
    msgType: SupportedMessageTypes // We should add more when we support them
    timestamp: bigint
    position: GeoPosition
    mid: string
    message: string // | Buffer // Will depend on if we send the
    // payload as compressed information or not
}

interface QueryResult {
    key: string
    item: OutputItemType
}

interface CursorResponse {
    cursorId: number
    items: QueryResult[]
}

class RedisController {
    private readonly redisClient: RedisClientType
    public readonly maxItemsPerQuery: number

    // Factory functions
    /**
     * Creates a RedisController from the given url
     * @param uri an url of the form:
     * redis[s]://[[username][:password]@][host][:port][/db-number]
     * pointing to the desired redis database
     * @returns A promise to a connected and configured RedisController object
     */
    static async from_uri(
        uri: string,
        maxItems: number = 5000
    ): Promise<RedisController> {
        const controller = new RedisController(uri, maxItems)
        try {
            await controller.connect()
            await controller.setup()
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
            process.exit(1)
        }
        return controller
    }

    private constructor(uri: string, maxItems: number) {
        this.maxItemsPerQuery = maxItems
        this.redisClient = createClient({ url: uri })
    }

    private async connect(): Promise<void> {
        return await this.redisClient.connect()
    }

    private async setup(): Promise<void> {
        await this.create_index()
        // Now try to disable redis search's MAXSEARCHRESULTS
        await this.redisClient.ft.configSet('MAXSEARCHRESULTS', '-1')
    }

    private async create_index(): Promise<void> {
        try {
            // We only want to sort by these 3 values so we
            // create an index schema with them they must be
            // of type any as redis does not export the types
            const schema: any = {
                mid: {
                    type: SchemaFieldTypes.TAG
                },
                msgType: {
                    type: SchemaFieldTypes.TAG
                },
                timestamp: {
                    type: SchemaFieldTypes.NUMERIC,
                    SORTABLE: true
                },
                position: {
                    type: SchemaFieldTypes.GEO
                }
            }
            const options: any = {
                ON: 'HASH',
                PREFIX: 'CITS'
            }
            await this.redisClient.ft.create('idx:cits', schema, options)
        } catch (e: any) {
            if (e.message === 'Index already exists') {
                console.log('Skipping index creation as it already exists.')
            } else {
                console.error(e)
                process.exit(1)
            }
        }
    }

    async get_total_query_items(queryString: string): Promise<number> {
        return (
            await this.redisClient.ft.search('idx:cits', queryString, {
                LIMIT: { from: 0, size: 0 }
            })
        ).total
    }

    async get_items_by_query(queryString: string): Promise<QueryResult[]> {
        // a ft.search query with LIMIT 0 0 gives the total number of
        // documents that match that index and query
        const totalDocs = await this.get_total_query_items(queryString)
        // cursor refers to the position of the last read item from the query
        let cursor = 0
        let documentList: any[] = []
        do {
            const queryResult = await this.redisClient.ft.search(
                'idx:cits',
                queryString,
                { LIMIT: { from: cursor, size: this.maxItemsPerQuery } }
            )
            cursor += queryResult.documents.length
            documentList = documentList.concat(queryResult.documents)
        } while (cursor < totalDocs)

        return documentList.map((item) => {
            return {
                key: item.id,
                item: RedisController.parse_to_item(item.value)
            }
        })
    }

    async get_items_by_query_stream(
        queryString: string
    ): Promise<RedisQueryStream> {
        const totalDocs = await this.get_total_query_items(queryString)

        const responseStream = await RedisQueryStream.createStream(
            this,
            queryString,
            totalDocs
        )

        return responseStream
    }

    private static cursor_results_to_query_results(element: any): QueryResult {
        const item = RedisController.parse_to_item(element)
        const key = RedisController.parse_to_key(item)
        return {
            key,
            item
        }
    }

    async _create_cursor(
        queryString: string,
        maxItems: number
    ): Promise<CursorResponse> {
        // NOTICE: with this approach we will need to update this hardcode
        // everytime
        const result = await this.redisClient.ft.aggregateWithCursor(
            'idx:cits',
            '*',
            {
                COUNT: 100,
                LOAD: [
                    { identifier: '@timestamp' },
                    { identifier: '@mid' },
                    { identifier: '@message' },
                    { identifier: '@msgType' },
                    { identifier: '@position' }
                ]
            }
        )

        const itemsArray: QueryResult[] = result.results.map(
            RedisController.cursor_results_to_query_results
        )
        return { cursorId: result.cursor, items: itemsArray }
    }

    async _read_from_cursor(cursorId: number): Promise<CursorResponse> {
        const result = await this.redisClient.ft.cursorRead(
            'idx:cits',
            cursorId
        )
        const itemsArray: QueryResult[] = result.results.map(
            RedisController.cursor_results_to_query_results
        )
        return { cursorId: result.cursor, items: itemsArray }
    }

    async _get_items_subset(
        queryString: string,
        from: number,
        maxItems: number
    ): Promise<QueryResult[]> {
        const queryResult = await this.redisClient.ft.search(
            'idx:cits',
            queryString,
            {
                LIMIT: { from, size: maxItems }
            }
        )

        return queryResult.documents.map((item) => {
            return {
                key: item.id,
                item: RedisController.parse_to_item(item.value)
            }
        })
    }

    async get_item_by_key(key: string): Promise<OutputItemType> {
        const item = await this.redisClient.hGetAll(key)
        return RedisController.parse_to_item(item)
    }

    /**
     * This function converts the redis representation of the objects to
     * OutputItemType
     * @param item item returned by redis query, converts it into the
     * OutputItemType representation
     * @returns the parsed OutputItemType
     */
    public static parse_to_item(item: any): OutputItemType {
        const coords: string[] = (item.position as string).split(',')
        const position: GeoPosition = {
            longitude: parseFloat(coords[0]),
            latitude: parseFloat(coords[1])
        }

        const result: OutputItemType = {
            mid: item.mid,
            // We need to use strings because json parser does not know how
            // to parse bigints
            timestamp: BigInt(item.timestamp),
            msgType: item.msgType,
            position,
            message: item.message
        }
        return result
    }

    private parse_to_item_array(items: any[]): OutputItemType[] {
        return items.map((item) => {
            return RedisController.parse_to_item(item)
        })
    }

    /**
     * Generates the key for a particular item
     * @param item
     * @returns the key representing this item inside the redis db
     */
    private static parse_to_key(item: OutputItemType): string {
        return (
            `CITS:${item.timestamp}:${item.msgType}:` +
            `${item.position.longitude}:` +
            `${item.position.latitude}:${item.mid}`
        )
    }

    async cleanup(): Promise<void> {
        await this.redisClient.quit()
    }

    async force_cleanup(): Promise<void> {
        await this.redisClient.disconnect()
    }
}

class RedisQueryStream extends stream.Readable {
    private readonly maxItemsPerQuery = 5000
    private readonly queryString: string
    private readonly total: number = 0
    private readonly controller: RedisController

    private cursorId: number = 0
    private cursor: number = 0
    private storedQuery: QueryResult[] = []
    private storedQueryCursor: number = 0

    static async createStream(
        controller: RedisController,
        queryString: string,
        total: number
    ): Promise<RedisQueryStream> {
        const result = new RedisQueryStream(controller, queryString, total)
        await result.createCursor()
        return result
    }

    private constructor(
        controller: RedisController,
        queryString: string,
        total: number
    ) {
        super({ objectMode: true, highWaterMark: Math.pow(2, 16) })
        this.controller = controller
        this.queryString = queryString
        this.total = total
    }

    private async createCursor(): Promise<void> {
        const response = await this.controller._create_cursor(
            this.queryString,
            this.maxItemsPerQuery
        )
        this.cursorId = response.cursorId
        this.storedQuery = response.items
    }

    async _read(size: number): Promise<void> {
        if (this.storedQueryCursor >= this.storedQuery.length) {
            this.storedQueryCursor = 0
            const cursorResult = await this.controller._read_from_cursor(
                this.cursorId
            )
            this.storedQuery = cursorResult.items
            if (cursorResult.cursorId === 0) {
                this.emit('end')
                return
            }
        }

        this.cursor += 1
        // We have to trick the typescript type system into thinking this
        // is a bigint. This result will always go through a JSON stringifier
        // and it does not know how to stringify bigints
        this.storedQuery[this.storedQueryCursor].item.timestamp =
            this.storedQuery[
                this.storedQueryCursor
            ].item.timestamp.toString() as unknown as bigint
        this.push(this.storedQuery[this.storedQueryCursor])
        this.storedQueryCursor += 1
    }
}

export { RedisController, QueryResult, CursorResponse, RedisQueryStream }
```

I have two classes in that file, the first, RedisController manages the redis connection and exposes some functions to get the items from the database using a simple query (no streaming of the data just bulk transfers) and also a function that creates the second class. The second class is a RedisQueryStream that extends `node:stream`'s `stream.Readable` Which on construction creates a cursor from which I consume (I cache some results not to be all the time querying the db) everytime _read() is called on the object.

As for the express application,

```js
import express from 'express'
import JSONStream from 'jsonstream'
import stream from 'node:stream/promises'

import { RedisController } from './redis_controller'

import { createGzip } from 'node:zlib'

async function main(): Promise<void> {
    const app = express()

    const redisController = await RedisController.from_uri(
        'redis://localhost:6379'
    )

    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
    app.use(express.json())

    app.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            const totalDocs = await redisController.get_total_query_items(
                req.query
            )
            console.log(`Sending ${totalDocs}...`)

            const redisQueryStream =
                await redisController.get_items_by_query_stream(req.query)
            // res.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'gzip')
            await stream.pipeline(
                redisQueryStream,
                JSONStream.stringify(),
                // createGzip(),
                res.type('json')
            )
        } catch (error) {
            next(error)
        }
    })

    app.use((err: any, req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
        console.error(err.stack)
        res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
    })

    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log(`Listening on http://localhost:3000...`)
    })
}

if (require.main === module) {
    main().catch((err) => {
        console.error(err)
        process.exit(1)
    })
}
```

Is _read() being an async function the problem? If so, how could I correctly implement the stream?

Comment: try piping that gzip stream to a file then verify it.

Comment: or store that redis data in json file then use that file as stream source. eg ```await stream.pipeline(createReadStream('/tmp/redis_data.json'), createGzip(), res.type('json'))
``` (just for testing purpose)

Comment: @bogdanoff Okay, somehow dumping all the objects to a file using `await stream.pipeline( resultStream, JSONStream.stringify(), createWriteStream('./original_uncompressed.json'))` gets stuck so I will try to investigate it!

Comment: @bogdanoff It is strange because the redisQueryStream is being called the 56800 times and then emits the end event using `this.emit(end)` but the pipeline still gets stuck, and the file is writter but with many less records. I don't know what is happening honestly.

Comment: can you update question with `redisQueryStream` source code or where it comes from ?.

Comment: @bogdanoff I have updated the question with the source code. It is my first time trying to implement an stream so it will probably be the culprit here

Comment: You're not showing the use of `createGzip()`. This smells of not closing the stream.

Comment: @MarkAdler But I am emitting the end event when i have no more data to send to the user, and Ieaved createGzip() commented in order to check the difference

Comment: I think its because of `_read` implementation, it doesn't seems quite right to me. Are you confident  ?, I know you are trying to batch process data while iterating but implementation doesn't seems right.

Comment: @bogdanoff Thank you for helping! In the end I have changed the implementation to not use streams, as cursors were not working correctly for me either.